# When is the calculate method of Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer\ProductPriceCalculator executed?

Tags: magento2

I have overridden the implementation of `Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer\ProductPriceCalculator` with my own in order to have catalog price rules applied to the special price instead of the price. It used to work fine but broke when I updated to 2.3.2.

So now I'm trying to debug my implementation to try to see what's going on. I tried using XDebug to set a breakpoint inside the calculate method, but running `bin/magento indexer:reindex` doesn't trigger it.

So my question is, when is this method used? How can I trigger it reliably?

Thank you!